# Why are 100 px in Adobe XD smaller than on a website (Safari, Google Chrome etc.)?

Tags: html, css, adobe, adobe-xd

I'd like to develop my design from Adobe XD. Unfortunately, the measurements are completely different. What's the reason for this? How can I calculate the "correct" size for elements and fonts?

[size in Adobe XD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARLJt.png)

[size on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Fkr.png)

Comment: I think adobe xd file view in 75%

Comment: check top right side

Comment: @LaljiTadhani but this is just the view, isn't it? But artboard is 1920 x 1080.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your html code needs to have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `head`
   container.
2. Make sure your browser is at 100% zoom
3. Make sure AdobeXD is also at 100%

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-xd-discussions/which-unit-does-adobe-xd-use-for-pixel-sizing/m-p/11921276/page/4) Adobe XD Support site, it doesn't seem like this issue will be fixed anytime soon.

One did suggest to use a web 1366 width workspace though, which seemed to solve their issue.

Another user suggested to see Adobe XD as unit-less, and only focus on the spacing between the different elements.